# How to collect a certain string anywhere in an item in a ListBox?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to find out how to collect a string anywhere in a Listbox, I use Visual Basic 2010 and this is more of an request, but there is code I found so you fix the code I found or tell me me an another code to use.

I have tried using ListBoxName.Items.Contains but that did not work, I tried a lot of methods and it would be hard to say all of then at once.

```
        ' Split string based on space
        Dim textsrtring As String = ListBox.Text
        Dim words As String() = textsrtring.Split(New Char() {" "c})
        Dim found As Boolean = False

        ' Use For Each loop over words
        Dim word As String
        For Each word In words
            If ListBox.Items.Contains(word) Then
                found = True

                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        MessageBox.Show(found)
```

They were no errors, the message box that appeared kept on telling me false and there is no string when I clearly put it in, no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an inner loop to see if each word is contained in your main listbox entry using String.Contains():

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim searchFor As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim
    If searchFor.Length > 0 Then
        Dim words As String() = searchFor.Split(New Char() {" "c})
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        Dim foundAt As Integer
        ' Use For Each loop over words
        Dim word As String
        For Each word In words
            For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox.Items.Count - 1
                If ListBox.Items(i).ToString.Contains(word) Then
                    found = True
                    foundAt = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If found Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If found Then
            ListBox.SelectedIndex = foundAt
            Label1.Text = "Search string found."
        Else
            ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1
            Label1.Text = "Search string NOT found."
        End If
    Else
        ListBox.SelectedIndex = -1
        Label1.Text = "No search string."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There are a few questions with your answer, I am not good with Visual Basic so how would I set the string to find? I also added something that shows what found equals, but when I did not add word, it said true, this is more related with the second question, sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Added a more in-depth example to show more use cases.  The search string is coming from TextBox1.  Added in how to show which entry in the ListBox was the match by selecting it.